# Manipular String en Subconsultas SQL

Tags: sql

tengo una serie de datos obtenidos a través de subconsultas, del resultado necesito convertir el formato de varchar a datetime y al querer manipular la cadena, la función REPLACE me arroja el siguiente error:

*"El tipo de datos text del argumento no es válido para el argumento 1 de la función replace.*"

```
 SELECT t.hora_inicio , RELACE (t.hora_inicio, ',', ':') as hora_inicio_modificada    -> ERROR 
   FROM (       
        SELECT campos...
        FROM tabla1 
        INNER JOIN tabla2 ON...
        WHERE ...
        AND ...
       ) as alias1,
      (SELECT tabla1.columna FROM tabla1 WHERE ... AND ...) as hora_inicio -> campo que debo convertir       
   FROM tabla3e
        INNER JOIN ...          
        WHERE ...
   AND ... ) t
```

Al utilizar Replace con otro campo de la tabla1 no tengo inconveniente, entiendo que el problema está con los datos que se generan dinámicamente a través del select  (SELECT tabla1.columna FROM tabla1 WHERE ... AND ...) as hora_inicio.

La consulta es mas compleja, solo intento reflejar lo necesario para solucionar el problema.

Gracias!

Comment: `t.hora_inicio` pareciera ser del tipo `text` y no funcionaría el `replace` trata de convertir la columna a un `varchar` antes.

Comment: Estás escribiendo `RELACE()` y en vez de `REPLACE()`